# How to bind keycode of key in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, events, keyboard

In title my problem was described, but here details.

I want to make a binding that can work with all keyboard layouts.

I tried add bind by "(symbol)Key-keycode(symbol)" and just "keycode" but it didn't work. Seems it's accepts only symbols.

I think I need dig deeper into wiki. But I can't find information about it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Tkinter key bindings are typically done by a given key name, e.g.: `root.bind('a', lambda event: print(event.keysym))` will print the letter 'a' every time the `A` key is pressed

Comment: You see, keybinds by symbol seems only work on English layout. But I want to make it work on other layouts as well. And I tried to get the keycode of the key that passed through event var. On different layouts keycode was the same. If I can't do this, maybe there is a diffrent solution?

Comment: If you want to bind specific keys by their symbol, I think tkinter (or probably more accurately, tcl) only understands a particular subset of symbols. I suppose a workaround would be to set up a general event handler bound to `'<Key>'`, and use the passed-in `event.keysym` to handle specific functionality for the given key. If you want, I can put together an example as an answer below. EDIT: [see here](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/KeySyms+on+platforms+other+than+X11) - looks like you're limited to X11 keysyms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a general event handler that leverages `match` (available in Python 3.10 and higher)

```
import tkinter as tk


def key_handler(event)
    match event.keysym:
        case '<insert your symbol here>':
            ...  # do something
        case '<insert anyther symbol here>':
            ...  # do something else
        case _:  # fallback / default case (yes, this should be an underscore)
            pass  # do nothing


root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Key>', key_handler)
root.mainloop()
```

This approach is flexible in that it lets you handle any number of `'<Key>'` events with a single function, but the caveat is that it will fire on *every* keypress. Any `keysym` that doesn't have a matching `case` will fall through. This isn't likely to be a huge performance hit, but it's something to be aware of!